# I need to call ACTION METHOD in button click using MVC angular JS

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

The script file which im using. While Im running it on IE it shows javascript runtime error angular is undefined.

```
 alert("hi");
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
alert("xxxxx");
myapp.controller("myctrl",
function ($scope, $http, $location) {
alert("inside fun;")
$scope.SaveFeedback = function () {
        alert("savefeedback called");
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/SaveFeedback',
            data: {
                Fornecedor: $scope.fornecedor
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-formurlencoded' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert("in success fun");
            $location.path("/Home/Index");
        }).error(function () {
            alert("error");
        });

    };
});
  alert("end");
```

Comment: can you make sure angular js file is loaded before this piece of code executes?

Comment: Before code executes I added four references... here it is but its still throwing angular is undefined
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-resource.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-resource.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-route.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js" />

Comment: how about creating a demo page in plnkr then we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: plnkr ? I didt understand

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. http://plnkr.co/  is a website to help create demos quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you inject the angular app in your html? like: `<body ng-app="myapp">` also you need to inject the angular-route etc in your app, when you declare the module.

Comment: not using .html file. im using .cshtml. i used like <div ng-app="my app">.Wait I try as per yur post

Comment: Thank yu so much. Its working.that javascript run time error angular runtime error cleared. but function inside the mypp.controller("myctrl",function...... )  is not firing

Comment: I believe the right syntax for controller is `myapp.controller("myctrl", [function () {....}])`

Comment: Also, the way you define your function now it won't be fired automatically, it has to be called first (for example with a ng-click)

Answer (score 0):

Appears like you havn't included the Angular JS library in the head. Please include

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

in the head and try else you can download and add to script folder and then refer in the head.

Comment: I added these four references..
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-resource.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-resource.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-route.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js" />